# Access Denied to document library for some users, while users with same permissions have no issues

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, permissions, access-denied, custom-permission-level

Using SharePoint Online, I have set up unique permissions on a document library so that users in the "Site Visitors" read-only group have the ability to add documents to this particular library.  I did this by making a copy of the "Read" permission level and adding "Add" rights to the copy, then assigning this new permission level to the visitors group on this library.

I have a handful of users who receive an "Access Denied" page when attempting to navigate to the library.  All of the users who both do and do not have issues accessing the library have access through the same Active Directory group.  I confirmed that permissions between a user who can and cannot access the library are the same by using the "check permissions" tool on the library permissions page.

I am at a loss as to what the issue could be.  Any ideas are appreciated.

Comment: In addition, please remove affected users and grant permission again to compare the result.

Comment: Am I removing and re-adding the AD group that the users have permissions through, or am I removing and re-adding the users to the group itself?

Comment: remove affected user in the group and re-add the users to the group, if the issue still exists, grant the affected user permissions directly and check the result

Answer (score 0):

Verify the users those are facing permission issues have the **limited access permissions** at the site level. Limited access permissions can be maintained by the site feature.

Give **NT AUTHORITY\authenticated** users and Everyone to READ Only by following the below steps :

Site actions > site settings > Master Page and page layouts > Library tab > Permissions. Add All authenticated users to READ ONLY.

Answer (score 0):

1. Can you please check again with them by clearing their browser cache? OR
2. Remove the users (those who are having issues accessing that library) from the Zeroth group and provide them similar kind of access again.

You can access the zeroth group of your site by appending below URL after your site collection name and accessing it.

/_layouts/15/people.aspx?MembershipGroupId=0